In C# Email Sending - using CKEditor 5 for body of email, OnValidSubmit Email body shows field is empty after entered text ,why?
Created C# Email Sending in Blazor Server App, Before using CKEditor 5 for Email body-Under fluent validation (OnValidSubmit), its working fine but After Using CKEditor 5 for Email Body, body field show empty after entered data.
Entered data in CKEditor 5 Body field, On Validation its showing body is empty, but without Validation for body it works, I expect it to work on Validation
EmailRequest EmailRequest { get; set; } = new();
private string? FileUploadError { get; set; }
private string? EmailSendResult { get; set; }
private string? EmailResultClass { get; set; } // Bootstrap class for success/error styling
  
async Task SendEmail()
{
    // Fetch CKEditor content and assign it to the EmailRequest.Body
    EmailRequest.Body = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getEditorContent", "editor");
     
    // Now run the validation or proceed with sending the email
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailRequest.Body))
    {
        EmailSendResult = "The email body cannot be empty.";
        EmailResultClass = "alert-danger";
        return; // Prevent email from being sent if the body is empty
    }

   
    try
    {
        var email = new MimeMessage();

        // Set the From address
        email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("EmailID"));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailRequest.To))
        {
            foreach (var toAddress in EmailRequest.To.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(toAddress.Trim()));
            }
        }
       
        // Set the Subject
        email.Subject = EmailRequest.Subject ?? "No Subject";

        
        // Create the body of the email
        var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder
            {
                HtmlBody = EmailRequest.Body
            };
       
        email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

        // Send the email
        using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
        smtp.Authenticate("emailID", "Password");
        smtp.Send(email);
        smtp.Disconnect(true);

        // Show success message
        EmailSendResult = "Email sent successfully!";
        EmailResultClass = "alert-success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Show error message if something goes wrong
        EmailSendResult = $"Failed to send email: {ex.Message}";
        EmailResultClass = "alert-danger";
    }
}
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // Initialize CKEditor with the id of the textarea
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeCKEditor", "editor");
    }
}


}

